# Azure Media Player does not play in IE

Tags: azure-media-services

With Azure Media Services we can upload video, encode it and get 3 URL's withing locator:

- Smooth Streaming URL
- HLS URL
- MPEG DASH URL

Then, you can add Azure Media Player on the web page and it is supposed to work on all browsers and devices. 
I noticed, that event on my one device (PC under Windows) the same video works fine in Chrome and Firefox but does not work with IE.

Here is 3 URL I have got after encoding:

- [Smooth Streaming](https://gvmedia.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0f682f61-21bb-458b-beb0-f22e84883617/video.ism/manifest)
- [MPEG-DASH](https://gvmedia.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0f682f61-21bb-458b-beb0-f22e84883617/video.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf))
- [HLS v4](https://gvmedia.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0f682f61-21bb-458b-beb0-f22e84883617/video.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl))

And all of these URLs does not work with IE11 on [demo site](https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=%2F%2Fgvmedia.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F0f682f61-21bb-458b-beb0-f22e84883617%2Fvideo.ism%2Fmanifest). 
Am I missing something?